# PrintWindow grabs zoomed image if target process is on second monitor

Tags: c#, image, screenshot

So I'm working on a program that will grab a screenshot of a target process.  For the demo process, I'm grabbing the Windows Calculator application.  When the calculator application is on my main monitor, the image generated (saved as a Bitmap) is perfect.  However, if I move the application to my side monitor (larger than my main monitor), it captures a zoomed in version.  The image dimensions are the same as if the calculator was on my main monitor, but the actual image captured is larger than the region, so part of the bottom and right of the image gets cut off.  If I check the rectangle dimensions, the dimensions are correct, its just that the actual image data collected is scaled up for some reason.  I was wondering if there was a way around this.  Included below are the code that I'm using to capture the picture, and to save it.

W8ScreencapUtils.cs:

```
//http://www.code4copy.com/csharp/post/getting-window-rect-using-handle-on-windows-8-and-other
class W8ScreencapUtils
{
    [DllImport(@"dwmapi.dll")]
    private static extern int DwmGetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int dwAttribute, out Rect pvAttribute, int cbAttribute);

    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct Rect
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;

        public Rectangle ToRectangle()
        {
            Rectangle rect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
            return rect;
        }
    }

    [DllImport(@"user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rect lpRect);

    private static Rectangle GetWindowRect(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Rect rect;
        GetWindowRect(handle, out rect);
        return rect.ToRectangle();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get real window size, no matter whether Win XP, Win Vista, 7 or 8.
    /// </summary>
    public static Rectangle GetWindowRectangle(IntPtr handle)
    {

        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major < 6)
        {
            return GetWindowRect(handle);
        }
        else
        {
            Rectangle rectangle;
            return DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS(handle, out rectangle) ? rectangle : GetWindowRect(handle);
        }
    }

    private enum Dwmwindowattribute
    {
        DwmwaExtendedFrameBounds = 9
    }

    private static bool DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS(IntPtr handle, out Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        Rect rect;
        var result = DwmGetWindowAttribute(handle, (int)Dwmwindowattribute.DwmwaExtendedFrameBounds,
            out rect, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Rect)));
        rectangle = rect.ToRectangle();
        return result >= 0;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

    public static Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        Rectangle rc = GetWindowRectangle(hwnd);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();

        PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);

        gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
        gfxBmp.Dispose();

        return bmp;
    }
```

From Form1.cs

```
    private void buttonCaptureCalculator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Start searching for the Calculator window
        toolStripStatusMainLabel.Text = "Searching for Calculator...";
        Console.WriteLine("Searching for Calculator...");
        IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        foreach(Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if(pList.MainWindowTitle.Equals("Calculator"))
            {
                toolStripStatusMainLabel.Text="Found Calculator!";
                Console.WriteLine("Found Calculator");
                hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
            }
        }
        //Breakout if Calculator wasn't found
        if(hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            toolStripStatusMainLabel.Text = "Couldn't find Calculator...";
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find Calculator...");
            return;
        }


        //Take a screenshot of the Calculator.
        toolStripStatusMainLabel.Text = "Aquiring screenshot of Calculator...";
        Console.WriteLine("Aquiring screenshot of Calculator...");
        Bitmap bmp = W8ScreencapUtils.PrintWindow(hWnd);

        //TEST: Save the screenshot to see if it worked;
        bmp.Save("C:\\Junk\\test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

        bmp.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Google "dpiaware dpiaware dpiaware".  Three times to make sure you get them all.

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know what to search, am fairly new to C# programming, so sorry about the silly/newbie question.  I'll look it up!